# pandas tranform list of custom object to dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science

I have list of objects.
Every object is from the class Student that has the attributes: name, id, grades.
grades is a dictionary with string keys ('math','cs',..).
I want to convert this list of pandas dataframe:

```
df = name id math cs
      a    2  90  92
      b    5  82  96
```

What is the best way to do so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let us try iterating over the `students` list and create a record for each `Student` object by retrieving the required attributes, then you can construct a new dataframe from these records

```
df = pd.DataFrame([{'name': s.name, 'id': s.id, **s.grades} for s in students])
```

In case you have variable number of instance attributes and there is always an attribute named `grades` present which contains marks of student stored in dictionary

```
df = pd.DataFrame(map(vars, students))
df = df.join(pd.DataFrame([*df.pop('grades')]))
```

---

```
  name  id  math  cs
0    a   2    90  92
1    b   5    82  96
```

Comment: Is there a way to do it without explicitly write every attribute? In case there will be more in the future

Comment: @okuoub It depends on what type of attributes the Student class contains,. Can you share the defination (`__init__ section`) of `Student` class?

Comment: def __init__(self, sid, name, l):
    self.id = sid #int
    self.name = name #string
    self.l = l #list

the dict is not part of __init__, it is added later